# How To Subtract Two Times Moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello every body i need help with moment js i've an input field called Start and another called stop

```
start = moment().format('LT'); // works when i click on the play button
stop  = moment().format('LT'); // works when i focus on the counter input beside the play button --> for test
```

i want to change the start input field manually so i want a validation function that takes the input value and check if the input is valid or not on this form `LT` for ex: when i delete the value of the input which is `6:39 PM` as below in the picture and type for example `6:02:00 PM or 1:00 PM or` add a string `5:dfds2 PM` i want to console log any error message `and return the previous value to the input again` also when i remove the current value and add a number like '1 for example' without `am or pm`  so it determines if the number is before or after than stop input value and type in the input field like this `1:00 AM or 1:00PM` i used this function to validate the start input field but it gives me wrong  answers

```
function validate(inputVal) {
  let temp =this.startTime;
  let x = temp;
  if(moment(inputVal, "hh:mm").isValid()) {
    x= moment(inputVal, "HH:mm").format('hh:mm A');
    console.log("inputVal is: " + inputVal + " and x is: " + x);
    this.startTime = x
  } else {
    this.startTime = "temp";
    console.log("no");
  }
}
```

here is the pic
[image]
for more info u can visit [toggl website](http://toggl.com) my idea is taken from there
any help ?! thanx in advance

Comment: your checking if `val` is valid on this line: `moment(val, "hh:mm").isValid()`. Do you mean to check your `inputVal`?

Comment: @enjoylife yes of course here `val == inputVal` i updated my Question thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and cleaned up your function a bit, reduced the logic, now you should just make sure the moment format is what your looking for

```
function validate(val) {
    let parsedTime = moment(val, "hh:mm");
    if (parsedTime.isValid()) {
        this.startTime =  parsedTime.format('hh:mm A');
    } 
}
```

Comment: thx but when i type like this exactly `5:bgb2` the input is `05:02 AM` which is not correct because there is `bgb` which made the input invalid or even when i type `5:10:` it also replaces the input field with this value this is not correct any ideas one more thing in the second condition `else` i want to take the start value which is for ex `1:25 Am` and if i wrote in the input field any invalid value it returns `1:25 Am` back to the input again not t`temp` value.